# Unable to sort records according to price laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sorting, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to sort the db records(tours) according to price (lowest to highest, highest to lowest). And I've added 12 dummy records in db with prices (100 to 1200) in series respectively. Below is my code in controller for performing the sort query:

```
    public function short(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->sortby == "lower") {
        $query = Tour::query()->orderBy('price', 'asc');
        if (!empty($request->country)) {
            $query = $query->whereHas('country', function($r) use($request) {
                $r->where('countries.name', $request->country);
            });
        }            

        if (!empty($request->category)) {
            $query = $query->whereHas('category', function($s) use($request) {
                $s->where('categories.name', $request->category);
            });
        }

        if ($request->days !== null) {
            $days = $request->days;
            $days_explode = explode('|', $days);
            $query = $query->whereBetween('days', [$days_explode[0], $days_explode[1]]);                    
        }
        $query = $query->get();   
    }
    else{
        $query = Tour::query()->orderBy('price', 'desc');            
        if (!empty($request->country)) {
            $query = $query->whereHas('country', function($r) use($request) {
                $r->where('countries.name', $request->country);
            });
        }            

        if (!empty($request->category)) {
            $query = $query->whereHas('category', function($s) use($request) {
                $s->where('categories.name', $request->category);
            });
        }

        if ($request->days !== null) {
            $days = $request->days;
            $days_explode = explode('|', $days);
            $query = $query->whereBetween('days', [$days_explode[0], $days_explode[1]]);                    
        }
        $query = $query->get();               
    }

    return view('public.tour.search')->withResults($query);
}
```

When sort by lowest to highest is selected, records are displayed in the following order according to price price column of db table:

`100,1000,1100,1200,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900`

and when highest to lowest is selected records are displayed in the following order according to price price column of db table:

`900,800,700,600,500,400,300,200,1200,1100,1000,100`

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: It looks to me as if Laravel tries to sort your numbers as strings. Are you sure the numbers are saved in an `INT` column (or any other numeric type) in your DB?

Answer (score 1):

What is the data type for the `price` column in the database?

It should be a numerical format like `double` or `integer` for the sorting to work correctly.

Comment: Is'nt this a comment?

Comment: No it's an answer. The issue is likely to do with the column type, hence the suggestion to change it to `integer` or `double`.

Comment: Ok cool, the thing i see question marks on your answer, asking for clarity, of which clarity can be asked in comments

Comment: this answer is correct, very correct. thanks man.... you actually need to change the data type to numeric .. `double` or `integer` if not it wont sort properly.

Answer (score 1):

Put the Order By Query at end.

```
$query = $query->orderBy('price', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: @NirajShah It does, If not please explain?

Comment: In Laravel, it DOES NOT make a difference. I have two queries: `User::where( 'first_name', 'LIKE', '%niraj%' )->orderBy( 'created_at', 'asc' )->get();` and `User::orderBy( 'created_at', 'asc' )->where( 'first_name', 'LIKE', '%niraj%' )->get();`.

If you enable query logging `DB::enableQueryLog()`, you will find that both produce exactly the same SQL:

`select * from `users` where `first_name` LIKE ? order by `created_at` asc`

In SQL, it does, since putting `ORDER BY` before `WHERE` causes a syntax error.